# Amazon S3 Client creating too many close_wait connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I am using AmazonS3Client for storing and accessing  images on the website. The problem is when an images is read it opens up a connection which stays in the close_wait state and overtime when all the ports are exhausted it causes the site to become unresponsive and only a restart of the IIS solves the problem temporarily.

Here is the method which is used for reading the images

```
public Stream Read(string path)
        {
            path = MapPath(path);

            var request = new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = BucketName, Key = path };

            using (var response = AmazonClient.GetObject(request))
            {
                var result = new MemoryStream();

                response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(result);

                result.Position = 0;

                return result;
            }
        }
```

How to close the connection after the image is read?